# Display text with spaces that are not copied

Tags: html, css

I want to display an account number on a website. To make it easier to read I'd like to put spaces in a couple of places to group the numbers. Easy. However, I'd like it so that when a user selects and copies that number, there won't be any spaces in the text when he pastes. So that it won't mess up online bank account fields that have a limit on number of characters for example.

Any ideas on how to solve this in a good way?

I'm thinking something along the following lines, but wondering if there are better ways.

```
// CSS
span.acc_no span {display:inline-block; margin: 0 .5em}

// HTML
<span class="acc_no">12345<span>12</span>1234</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats how I would do it.  If you don't want the spaces to show up when you copy the number, then you need to use some sort of padding or margin to give the appearance of a space.

CSS:

```
.acc_no span {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:0.5em;
}
.acc_no span:first-child {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="acc_no"><span>12345</span><span>12</span><span>1234</span></span>
```

Comment: :last-child is not supported in <IE7 so it would be better to apply padding-left: 0.5em; to .acc_no span and then padding-left: 0; to .acc_no span:first:child;

Comment: Ha, yeah that would be better.  Thanks @luca.

Comment: Almost same, but I like this better as you group each group, rather than just the ones that makes it look right :)

Comment: Yeah, I like it better that way too. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be using :after pseudo tag.

```
Here is your Account number: <span class="AccountNumber"><span>12345</span><span>12</span><span>1234</span></span>

.AccountNumber span:before
{
    content: " ";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/DUsUN/

Though that might depend on your browser compatibility requirements...

Edit: Thanks to jasssonpet for pointing out to me that the implementation of copying differs by browsers... FF and chrome do not copy the spaces added this way. IE does. This means this is probably not the best solution but still an interesting one to note so I'm not getting rid of it. :)

Comment: spaces are copied on ie and opera

Comment: Really? My tests (firefox) they weren't copied. When Is aid browser compatibility I was thinking more of whether :after was supported rather than how it did copying. :)